# The sum of products for a macro but is different in every time i get new data which is per month

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i need a formula or any help to find the total of (column I) i know a simple sum formula works but the problem is every month the data is different, the product is the same but the quantity and price change.

I put the appscripts code

```
​function sum_until_blank(cell_description, dummy) {
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var this_cell = sheet.getRange(cell_description);

if (this_cell.isBlank()) {
return 0;
}

var this_value = this_cell.getValue();
if (typeof this_value != "number") {
return 0;
}

next_cell = sheet.getRange(this_cell.getRow() + 1, this_cell.getColumn());
return this_value + sum_until_blank(next_cell.getA1Notation());
}
```

Copied from stack overflow question

This is how my data layout is and from above there is one row empty like to sheet is below

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8nQOulWpEn4qVcsJKtnZp_5WLmAomzKkJ6LKFUyNKA/edit#gid=0

The link to the sheet, any help would be highly appreciated.
I thought =sum(filter( could fix it but not very good at it and couldn't make it work , also an appscripts for this would also work (sum_until_blank) as above but don't know how to make it work automatically without manually adding =if(A:A="",sum_until_blank("I12",(I$12:I$999),B:B*E:E) also it just says loading data,i want to use apple scripts as a last resort so if theres a way to do it without appscripts, that would be fine too so any suggestion on how to make it work also suffice.

Thanks,
Vansh

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your showing image of your Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Okay so forget about the script i just need to find a way to sum the total automatically and get it in the macro to automate the p&l for every month i will delete the image and let the sheet link be

Comment: Must you include the units on each line? I would think a drop down in the next column would be more versatile

Comment: yes i guess that would also work but it should be compatible with a macro the end goal is to find the profit and loss of the month

Answer (score 0):

Partial Sums

```
function partialsums() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 4;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 9, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  let a = 0;
  let v = 0;
  vs.forEach((s, i) => {
    v = parseInt(s);
    if (!isNaN(v)) {
      a += v;
    } else if (a != '' && a > 0) {
      sh.getRange(i + 4, 9).setValue(a).setNumberFormat("0.###############");
      a = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi,cooper thank you so much for solving this is there any way the code can not go buy sheet by name because every month i will get a sheet named "august2022" so do i have to go the app scripts and change it everytime i run the macro?

Comment: Are you saying that you have no idea how to make it run on the active sheet?

Comment: i have no idea how to run it in a macro

Comment: i just add this code to the macro right?

Comment: That's too bad.  The only reason I learned Apps Script was so that I could write all of my most favorite personal management tools on my own.  Anyway I updated the code

Comment: Anyways i cant thank you enough for this. Thank you so much